# tinymce, youtube videos and the media plugin

Tags: youtube, tinymce

Im trying to add youtube videos using the media plugin but its not quite working.

I just choose iframe, drop in the URL to the youtube video and hit insert right?

Well its not working, it just like, makes an image placeholder instead.

This is the code it produces:

```
<img data-mce-json="{'type':'iframe','video':{'sources':[]},'params':{'src':'http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bw9S8DoKZXM','frameborder':'0'},'width':'425','height':'350'}" src="http://localhost:3000/javascripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/trans.gif">
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find one solution to your problem [here (tinymce forum thread).](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25674)

Comment: Link is not active anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin that seems doing what you need and more. It allows you to insert a youtube video into tinymce and the video is fully functional after that(meaning you can do play, stop...etc). The approach is different from tinymce built in feature but it also adds more flexibly because it can be used with google maps, image sliders, tabs..etc. Also the plugin is compatible with most popular "editable iframe" editors. Here is the link http://editorboost.net/WYSIWYGComponent

Comment: Link is not active anymore.

Answer (score -1):

you can try [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/)

This will for sure solve your issue... i would like to recommend you `tinymce` for embedding youtube videos.. for your website..